# Find all files which have been changed across all branches compared to a particular branch in git

Tags: git

Rather than just finding files changed between two branches, I'd like to find files which have changed between a branch (which would typically be main or dev) and all other branches.

For example, if I had a repo that had the following files:

```
├── f1
├── f2
├── f3
```

Suppose two branches were created, one which modified `f2` and one which modified `f3`, I would like to be able to do some form of `git show-files-changed-compared-to --branch=main`, and have `f2, f3` returned.

## Edit

From a comment:

> I think you're asking to have comparisons done between a specified branch-tip commit (e.g., the one selected by main) and all other branch-tip commits

I'm not familiar enough with how git works. I simply mean that if i have some file `f2.txt`, and two branches `main` and `feat-1` where `f1.txt` has content

```
something
```

on branch `main` and

```
something
something else
```

On branch `feat-1` then I would expect `f1.txt` to be output by the solution to the given question.

Comment: A possible way of proceeding could be to build a loop in bash over the lines of output from `git branch | grep -v f1`, then call `git diff --name-only f1 <branch>` on each iteration, finally send that into `| sort -u`

Comment: This question isn't really well-defined, as branches don't modify files: branch names point to specific (tip) commits and make ancestors of those tip commits reachable. Some commits are reachable from multiple branch tips and some are not. You need to decide here whether you want to consider *only* branch-tip commits, or all commits that are only reachable from any particular branch-tip.

Comment: I *think* you're asking to have comparisons done between a specified branch-tip commit (e.g., the one selected by `main`) and all other branch-tip commits. That's a lot easier and is what @RomainValeri suggested above.

Comment: @RomainValeri thanks - i don't think i follow, are you able to post a working example as an answer rather than a comment? `git branch | grep -v f1`  is going to display branch *names* and filter out branch names that have the _file name_ `f1` as a substring.

Comment: There's a confusion I introduced in my comment, sorry, I used `f1` as a placeholder for your reference branch, while it's in fact the name of the unchanging file. My bad. But I guess the overall idea still stands if you substitute the faulty `f1` in my example above with `main`

Comment: @RomainValeri `git branch -a | grep -v dev | xargs -I{} git diff --name-only {}  | sort -u` I guess ?